# Table View cellForRowAtIndexPath warning

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I have updated my code to swift 3.0 and get a warning on the following line:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

When I try each of the suggestions to either silence the warning with @nonobjc or make it a private function the table no longer loads.

The error reads:

> Instance method 'tableView(*:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'tableView(*:canFocusRowAt:)' of protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'

Does anyone know what causes this error and how to fix it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just add the declaration of implementing **UITableViewDataSource** protocol to the class definition like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {}
```

Answer (score 6):

In swift 3.0 the signature for the datasource changed to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Notice the difference between `cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath` and `cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath`

I'm using the new method without any warnings, hope this will solve your problem.

Cheers.

Comment: I didn't check swift3 yet, but really? That change doesn't make any sense.. Is there any reason behind? Or just to remove the redundant use of "indexPath"?

Comment: `remove the redundant` is indeed an important theme in Swift 3.

Comment: I've used that code and done a clean but its still giving me the same error :( When I expand the error it give a couple of indicators:  `Move 'tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)' to an extension to silence this warning` & `Requirement 'tableView(_:canFocusRowAt:)' declared here (UIKit.UITableViewDelegate)`

Comment: I think it's be because you didn't implement UITableViewDataSource in your viewcontroller

Comment: @MAB You may be right.  My UITableViewDataSource is a model object external to the view controller and I was getting the same error.  To reduce it to a warning I've had to add the following prefix to the function declaration `@objc(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) internal func tableView....`.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, and found that if you remove the space between the underscore before tableView, from this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: ...
```

to this

```
func tableView(_tableView: ...
```

strangely the warning goes away...